# R assign ID to records NOT using loops

Tags: r, loops, data.table, vectorization

I need to loop through a data table "A" and depending on a condition assign an incremental ID to that record or group of records like:

```
library(data.table)
A <- data.table(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14), 
  y = c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3), z = 0)

for(i in 1:nrow(A))
 {
   if((A[i]$x %% A[i]$y) == 0) {A[i]$z <- i}
   print(i)
 }
```

the z column becomes a sort of a rolling ID.
I need to perform the same operation without using loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you can try this (sinde x already contains the index value)

Update (by reference) z-value with x-value, on rows where condition `x %% y == 0` is met. On all other rows `z` keeps it's original value (i.e. 0).

```
A[ x %% y == 0, z:=x]

#     x y  z
# 1:  1 2  0
# 2:  2 2  2
# 3:  3 2  0
# 4:  4 2  4
# 5:  5 2  0
# 6:  6 2  6
# 7:  7 2  0
# 8:  8 2  8
# 9:  9 3  9
# 10:10 3  0
# 11:11 3  0
# 12:12 3 12
# 13:13 3  0
# 14:14 3  0
```

But of course you can also use `.I` to get the index of a row

```
A[ x %% y == 0, z := .I]
```

Will also work... depending on your column-classes, you will have to set some integer-columns to class double, to avoid warning messages.

## benchmarks

Up to 50000 rows, Ronaks' answer is faster, above that, the `.I` solution is 'winning'.

[image]

code used for benchmarking

```
vec <- c( seq( 1,10000, by = 1000), seq( 1,100000, by = 10000), 
          seq( 1,1000000, by = 100000), seq( 1,10000000, by = 1000000) )

l <- lapply( vec, function(x){
  A <- data.table(x = as.double( 1:x ), 
                  y = as.double( sample(2:3, x, replace = TRUE) ), 
                  z = as.double(0) )
  m <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    Ronak = { 
      DT <- copy(A)
      inds <- DT$x %% DT$y == 0
      DT$z[inds] <- which(inds)
    },
    Wimpel = {
      DT <- copy(A)
      DT[ x %% y == 0, z:=as.double(.I)]
    },
    times = 10 )
  setDT(m)[, .(n = x, median = median(time)), by = .(expr)][]
})

library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot( data = rbindlist(l), aes( x = n, y = median/1000000, group = expr, colour = expr )) + 
  geom_smooth( se = FALSE ) +
  labs( x = "rows",
        y = "median [ms]" )
```

Comment: Here's something slightly faster for larger rows and very similar to smaller row counts. ```A[['z']] <- A[['x']]; A[['z']][A[['x']] %% A[['y']] != 0 ] <- 0```. It's not the best looking but it does work in both base and data.table.

Answer (score 3):

You could get the index where `%%` operator returns 0 and assign the index value at the position.

```
inds <- A$x %% A$y == 0
A$z[inds] <- which(inds)

A
#     x y  z
# 1:  1 2  0
# 2:  2 2  2
# 3:  3 2  0
# 4:  4 2  4
# 5:  5 2  0
# 6:  6 2  6
# 7:  7 2  0
# 8:  8 2  8
# 9:  9 3  9
#10: 10 3  0
#11: 11 3  0
#12: 12 3 12
#13: 13 3  0
#14: 14 3  0
```